# Post to user wall after a form

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

first of all THANK YOU! Thanks to this community edit FB app is getting something possible for me too. Secondly, sorry for my bad english.

Here's my problem: I want to publish a message on user's wall, but only if they want. So i set up a form in which users can choice if publish a content on their wall or not. The problem is that when user send the form, i get an error message: OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action. So I'm sure it has something to do with access token, but i don't understand what's wrong. Here's my code:

```
<?php
require_once "fb_app/facebook.php";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '***',
    'secret' => '***',
    'cookie' => true
));
function grokSignedRequest() {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['signed_request'])) {
      $encoded_sig = null;
      $payload = null;
      list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $_REQUEST['signed_request'], 2);
      $sig = base64_decode(strtr($encoded_sig, '-_', '+/'));
      $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/'), true));
      return $data;
    }
    return false; }
$userID = $facebook->getUser(); 
$sr_dati = grokSignedRequest();
$firendsWall=$_POST['firendsWall'];
$likeStatus=$_POST['likeStatus'];
if ($sr_dati->page->liked==1 or $likeStatus==1) {
if ($userID) { // Checks if there is already a logged in user
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    // Will throw the very first time as the token is not valid
    error_log($e);
    $userID = null;
   }
}

if(empty($userID)) {  
    # There's no active session, let's generate one  
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(  
        "response_type"=>"token", //Can also be "code" if you need to 
        "scope" => 'email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream,user_photos,user_videos,photo_upload,user_status' , 
        "redirect_uri"=> "http://www.facebook.com/pages/V....." //Your app callback url 
    ));  
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '" . $login_url. "';</script>";  
    exit;  
} 
//pubblico contenuto sulla bacheca di un utente
if ($firendsWall==1){
    try {$args = array(
    'message'   => 'Hello',
    'link'      => 'aaaa',
    'caption'   => 'vvvvvv!'
);
$post_id = $facebook->api("/".$userID."/feed", "post", $args);}
 catch (FacebookApiException $f) {
    // Will throw the very first time as the token is not valid
    echo $f;} }}
?>
```

Comment: Did you add more permissions after you authorised the application? If yes, revoke the app authorisation and log into it again.

Comment: If you aren't authenticating the user for another reason, you could use the [feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)

Comment: @bartek: I did it, it doesn't work :/ Maybe that it's because when you send a form you lost the access key and such data?

Comment: 1. Is the 'redirect_uri' you provided with your code the real one? 2. Use [Facebook Debug Tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to check if your access token is valid (print it from your script and paste it into the tool) - this should determine if there's problem with your code or with your access token.

Comment: As 'redirect_uri' I used the tab link. Is it wrong? From the debug tool i received this: Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed

Small og:image: All the images referenced by og:image should be at least 200px in both dimensions. Please check all the images with tag og:image in the given url and ensure that it meets the recommended specification.

While creating the app, I used 'http://website.it/esterno/fb/gadget.php?' as canvas URL and 'http://website.it/esterno/fb/gadget.php' as page tab URL. Is it ok?